# Quickly finding arrangement of words in dictionary that fit a pattern

Tags: regex, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary of around 100,000 words, and I want to be able to find
arrangements of those words that fit certain patterns. The patterns can be
described as a list of integers, and a list of words matches that
pattern if there's a way of mapping the integers to letters such that if you
replace each integer in the pattern by the letter, you get that list of words,
concatenated.

As an example, let's suppose our dictionary contains:

```
A
ANA
APPLE
BANANA
...
```

And the pattern we're looking for is ([1]):

```
1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1
```

Then a solution is [ANA, BANANA], with the mapping:

1: A
  2: N
  3: B
  4: N
  5: N

Now, there are several approaches I can think of for how to implement this. For
example, we can pick every arrangement of words that has the right length, and
filter for those that don't have mapping conflicts. Or solve the problem
recursively, and with each pattern and mapping so far, trying out all words
that have length less than or equal to the pattern and don't conflict with the
mapping so far, the recursively calling this algorithm on the pattern that
remains, with the updated mapping.

But these solutions are horribly slow for the size of dictionary and pattern I
am working with. If the pattern `P` is of length `|P|`, and the dictionary `D`
of length `|D|`, and the average word length is `n`, then we are looking at
algorithms on the order of `O(|D|^{|P|/n})`. (I'm hoping to manage patterns of
size of 50-100 and imagine `n` is about 5.)

Is there a better algorithm?

---

[1] Note that this is a little like backreferences in regular expressions - e.g.
the pattern `1 2 1` corresponds to the regular expression `(.)(.)\1` - but we
can't just use regular expressions because the text being "searched" is not a fixed one but *any* arrangement of words in the dictionary.

Comment: I might not understand the question, but have you considered representing the dictionary as a set of tries?  The integer list sure looks like a handy index list into a trie.

Comment: If the dictionary is static, you can preprocess it: since ANA is a substring of BANANA, if BANANA fits the pattern , then ANA will fit it too. You may build some trees, with longest words at the top and their substrings as descendants. This would speed up the research.

Comment: Oh, I see @danh had the same idea (and a better expression for it). Addition: if the pattern is not normalized, it should be normalized before the research.

Comment: @danh if you mean what I think you mean, we end up with a worst case of `O(C^|P|)`, where `C` is the number of characters in the alphabet, which still seems pretty bad?

Comment: Not a solution, but a comment assuming that this is an English dictionary.  If you sort the numbers by frequency, odds are that the needed mapping won't be too far from the frequency distribution in English.  See https://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html for that.  This may help you make greedy choices that are likely to work out quickly.

Comment: Note that choosing the first word of the solution dramatically reduces the number of possible matches. In your example, if you choose "ANA" as the first word, then the pattern becomes "A N A 1 A 2 A 3 A". Prior to choosing "ANA", the words "BOB", "DID", "POP", etc are all possible matches for part of the pattern. But choosing "ANA" eliminates all of those words.

Comment: How fast do you need this to work?  I tried a simple trie-based solution with 58k words and it could find all solutions to length 50 patterns in about 10 minutes in Python.

Comment: What does this `1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1` mean ? You can create multiple ternary tree regex, which is a full trie. Each one you create, you can lop off the first letter of the previous words, until you have the number of tries equivalent to the number of the count of the largest word's letters. Each count represents a level within the first trie. If you match that level, you know where you are in a mapping scheme.

Comment: Does the word have to be fully consumed? That is, would "ANA" work for `[1 2]`, even though the final 'A' isn't matched?

Comment: If you can map multiple digits to the same letter it looks like you can match any pattern by using A repeatedly and mapping every digit to A.

Comment: @JimMischel yeah the word has to be fully consumed.

Comment: @mcdowella true, but it's not enough to find one solution - all of them have to be found.